# Dynamic comparison with surrounding cells in Python

Tags: python, iteration

I am trying to find the path of least resistance. For example, for element 1, I want the code to scan surrounding cells (2,4,5), pick the minimum (which is 2), then for 2, scan the surrounding elements (3,4,5,6) except 1 since I already traversed through 1. For 3, scan (5,6) and not 2 since in the previous step, I was at 2.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1, 2 , 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

A_min=A.argmin(axis=1)
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this algorithm? With what kind of data would this operation actually make sense? And what have you tried yourself to achieve the result? Is this about pathfinding and is the grid of data supposed to represent cost of traversal? If so, have you looked at Dijkstra's algorithm or A*?

Comment: I am not looking to find the shortest path between two points, but the path of least resistance just by scanning the adjacent elements, moving onto the next minimum and excluding the previous element.

Comment: The path of least resistance from where to where?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.